# Simple AppleScript for AutoMator

Tags: applescript, minecraft

I need a simple AppleScript for a game. Can anyone help and dedicate to me 1 minute to make it?

1) Press Esc

2) Press W key and hold it for 10 seconds

3) Press A key and hold it for 10 seconds

4) Press S key and hold it for 10 seconds

5) Press A key and hold it for 10second

Repeat this for unlimited time (BUT NOT STEP 1)

Thanks <3

Comment: This is not the place for others to do your work. Work on it yourself. We only exist to help you and try to resolve problems along the way.

Comment: You're right @Frontear, but we can still tell him (and others!) that his "need" is not achievable by AppleScript, can't we?

Answer (score 1):

"Simple" as your wish may be – AppleScript allows `"key down > … > key up" events` *ONLY* for modifier keys, so: *NOT* for `"W", "A"…`.

You *MIGHT* (with little hope) try to do some repeat loops (with: `keystroke "w"`) in your game, setting a variable `myNow` (previous to loop) to current time and repeat while current time is less than `myNow` plus 10 seconds.

[ Obviously, testing this in TextEdit, you'd write a massively long line of `wwwwwwwwwwwww … aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa … ssssssssssssssssssss …`   ]